# Making simple buttons to autoscroll to next and previous Id'd elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to web design, but have been tasked with making the website for an organization I'm in.

I've been googling with various keywords but my coding knowledge is only just starting on Javascript and CSS animations.

I'm trying to make a simple pair of buttons to scroll to the next and previous in a series of elements on a page.

A button that takes you to the previous section and a button that takes you to the next section, which is all on the same page.

Everything I've found so far is about having a list of the sections to click to, not two buttons that scrolls between them or it pertains to an image slideshow.

Any help here would be appreciated, Javascript or CSS.

I get the general Idea, I have to give each div a particular ID, set up an event to monitor what's currently in the viewport, and have the buttons set up to onclick to the previous or next sections, but I'm not familiar enough with CSS or Java to code either.

Comment: Note: Java and JavaScript are separate languages.

Answer (score 0):

Jumping to the next or previous `div` is plain HTML, e.g. your markup looks like:

```
<div id="first">First content</div>
<div id="second">Second content</div>
<div id="third">Third content</div>
```

Then you can use simple anchors to jump to the different parts, e.g.:

```
<a href="#second">Got to second</a> <!-- Jump to second part -->
```

Now if you want animated scrolling and not just jumping, you can use a suitable Javascript library, e.g. JQuery. CSS-Tricks has [a quite simple](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) example of doing smooth scrolling.